# Product Aggregate in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate

I try to create an aggregate for product (*) in PostgreSQL.
The field type of my row is "double precision"

So, I tried :

```
CREATE AGGREGATE nmul(numeric)
(
   sfunc = numeric_mul,
   stype = numeric
);
```

When I launch my query, the result :

```
ERROR:  function nmul(double precision) does not exist
LINE 4: CAST(nmul("cote") AS INT),
```

Thank you

Comment: You should probably show the SQL for the query the error came from.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found a solution from a very smart guy, who realized you can use logarithms to achieve this ([credit goes to him](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/gtmhfi%24u26%242%40reversiblemaps.ath.cx)):

```
select exp(sum(ln(x))) from generate_series(1,5) x;
 exp 
-----
 120
(1 row)
```

Comment: Numerical methods are used to calculate logs and exps, each needing a few iterations of some rather simple arithmetic operations.

Comment: @ChrisSH Of course not, but it can be used for negative numbers equally well when he wants to get the aggregate product.
E.g. if in the call above `x < 0` he should replace `x` with `z = -x` and multiply the result by `(-1)^x`.

Answer (score 8):

Cast your input from `double precision` (`float8`) to `numeric`, or define a `double precision` flavour of your aggregate.

Your aggregate works fine:

```
regress=> CREATE AGGREGATE nmul(numeric)
regress-> (
regress(>    sfunc = numeric_mul,
regress(>    stype = numeric
regress(> );

regress=> SELECT nmul(x) FROM generate_series(1,100) x;
                                                                              nmul                                                                              
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000
(1 row)
```

the issue is your query:

```
regress=> SELECT nmul(x::float8) FROM generate_series(1,100) x;                                                                                                                
ERROR:  function nmul(double precision) does not exist                                                                                                                         
LINE 1: SELECT nmul(x::float8) FROM generate_series(1,100) x;                                                                                                                  
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

You can define a `float8` version of your aggregate (`float8` is a synonym for `double precision`):

```
regress=> CREATE AGGREGATE nmul(double precision)
(
   sfunc = float8mul,
   stype = float8
);

regress=> SELECT nmul(x::float8) FROM generate_series(1,100) x;
         fmul          
-----------------------
 9.33262154439441e+157
(1 row)
```

or cast to `numeric` before aggregation if you want to retain the full precision of the value, eg:

```
CAST(nmul(CAST("cote" AS numeric)) AS INT)
```

or the PostgreSQL-specific shorthand cast:

```
nmul("cote"::numeric)::integer
```

Note that `integer` will overflow very quickly when you're working with these product aggregates:

```
regress=> SELECT nmul(x)::integer FROM generate_series(1,12) x;
   nmul    
-----------
 479001600
(1 row)

regress=> SELECT nmul(x)::integer FROM generate_series(1,13) x;
ERROR:  integer out of range
regress=>
```

so you're likely to want to stick with `numeric` anyway.