# Total percentage of a series of positive and negative percentages

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, percentage, multiplication

Postgres 9.6.6, latest Ubuntu LTS.
I have a column with a daily grow (+-) percentages, like:

```
Trader_Id   Date    8_AM    8_PM    Growth%
    1       1/1     290     248     -14,48
    1       2/1     225     880     291,11
    1       3/1     732     512     -30,05
    1       4/1     621     602      -3,06
    1       5/1     314     314        0,0
    1       6/1       0       0        0,0
    1       7/1     294     95      -67,69
```

What is the correct query to sum and subtract a sequence of percentages to get the total percentage of growth(+-) of the selected trader?
In that case, select a Trader_Id, sort by Date ASC and calculate a total growth percentage from the first day available.
This is the **sequence** of manual calculations:

```
Growth%     Calculation                                     Result  
-14,48      1+(-14,48/100)                                  0,8552
291,11      0,8552+(291,11/100*0,8552)                      3,34477272
-30,05      3,34477272+(-30,05/100*3,34477272)              2,339668518
-3,06       2,33966851764+(-3,06/100*2,33966851764)         2,268074661
    0       2,26807466100022+(0/100*2,26807466100022)       2,268074661
    0       2,26807466100022+(0/100*2,26807466100022)       2,268074661
-67,69      2,26807466100022+(-67,69/100*2,26807466100022)  0,732814923
            (0,73281492296917-1)*100                        -26,7185077
```

The final expected result of `SELECT SOMETHING(Growth% ORDER BY Date)` is **-26,72%**

Figured out the correct formula to do that:

[image: formula]

Now the remaining problem is how to traduce in a correct SQL...

Comment: You have to first define the base of each percentage. Is it the previous row? Then we have to consider compound interest. Or is it some stable value? Then we can just add up percentages. Also: Why is this tagged [plpgsql]? What is your version of Postgres? How is the sort order of rows established? Are there NULL values / days with no percentage? Best provide your table definition - a `CREATE TABLE` statement showing data types and constraints.

Comment: Thanks Erwin, I update my question to better explain the problem.

Comment: Alsdo show us the expected output for this sample data in tabular format

Comment: I update the question with the sequence of manual calculations and the final result. Thanks

Comment: it seems to me that for cumulative percentages you really want the product of the normalised percentages not the sum.

Comment: Updated the question with the correct formula to do the work. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For lack of information *assuming* your column `growth` is type `numeric` and you want `numeric` precision for calculation as well.

(Calculating with `double precision` is cheaper, but may increase rounding errors.)

Create an aggregate function to generate a serial product *once*:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE numeric_mul(numeric) (
   sfunc = numeric_mul,
   stype = numeric
);
```

Then the query is as simple as:

```
SELECT 100 * numeric_mul(growth *.01 + 1) - 100
FROM   tbl;
```

*[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=60760fbdec85d32cd1fd4533d611d78e) here*

The order of input rows has no bearing on the result.

Related:

- [Product Aggregate in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156055/product-aggregate-in-postgresql/13156170#13156170)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a column referring to the day and you would like to know the sum of percentages for the current week.

You could do

```
SELECT SUM(day_percent)
  FROM t
 WHERE calendar_day BETWEEN 
date_trunc('week',calendar_day) AND 
date_trunc('week',calendar_day) + INTERVAL '7 DAYS';
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e5767/1)